# Why does my Internet connection switch on and off?

Tags: internet

My internet works for a couple minutes when the computer turns on then it says

> can't connect to servers

and my downloads stop. I am running 12.10 and I am using a Asus USB N13 to connect to the internet.

The weird thing is it says I am still connected.

Comment: have you set your network addresses manually?

Answer (score 0):

What output do you get from `ifconfig` when the connection goes down?

Might also be a firewall issue. Try `sudo iptables --flush`